# Opening the pending edits when there is a fragment identifier to a comment in the url

Tags: bug, suggested-edits

I open a question from a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43390384/how-can-i-style-the-whole-logo-including-text-and-image-to-become-a-link-to-the/43390421#comment73841858_43390421) under my comments activity in my profile. The link include a hash to the relevant comment (`#comment73841858_43390421`).

Currently there is a pending edit for this question, so I clicked on that link, which opens the edit dialog, but it also scroll to the comment, so I have to scroll up in order to see the dialog.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Open a question with pending edit that has a fragment identifier in the URL to a comment (Example: [How can I style the whole logo including text and image to become a link to the homepage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43390384/how-can-i-style-the-whole-logo-including-text-and-image-to-become-a-link-to-the/43390421#comment73841858_43390421))
2. Click on the *edit* link to open the suggested edits dialog under the question body.

**Expected**: The dialog will open and the browser will NOT scroll again to the comment location

**Actual**: The dialog opens, but the browser jumps to the comment (Note that it only happens the first time you click on the edit link, it won't jump if you close the dialog and open it again)

Tested on Chrome v57